# Python Discord Bot Image Edit

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

the bot does not respond to the image I sent with the command.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"message from {message.author} what he said {message.content}")

@bot.command()
async def AmetyStsteve(ctx):
    if len(ctx.message.attachments) > 0:
        img = Image.open(requests.get(ctx.message.attachments[0].url, stream=True).raw)
        img.save('example.png')
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('example.png'))
        os.remove('example.png')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Send Image Pls')
```

the bot should get the image to edit and send back, but this does not happen
The question is: how to make a photo sent to a bot be edited or at least forwarded back. I'm stuck on the fact that the bot is not getting an image. Yes the folder has access.

Comment: What's the question? Where are you stuck? Are you able to locate the file? Did you use absolute path? Does the folder you use have writing permissions for this user?

Comment: The question is: how to make a photo sent to a bot be edited or at least forwarded back.
I'm stuck on the fact that the bot is not getting an image.
Yes the folder has access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you receive the image as an argument to the command. Follow this example to receive an image, download it, edit it with PIL, and resend it:

```py
from PIL import Image

@bot.command()
async def edit(ctx: commands.Context, image: discord.Attachment):
    # to pass the image parameter, simply attach a file to the command message

    # convert the attachment to a discord file
    file = await image.to_file()

    # open the image with pil and edit it
    img = Image.open(file.fp).convert('RGB')
    img = img.resize((400, 400))
    
    # save the edited image 
    img_bytes = BytesIO()
    extension = file.filename.split(".")[-1]
    img.save(img_bytes, format=extension)
    img_bytes.seek(0)
    file.fp = img_bytes
    img.close()

    # send the image
    await ctx.reply("Edited image:", file=file)
```

Comment: Thanks, is working, but I found a solution yesterday